# Displaying house numbers with nokia map image API

Tags: maps, here-api

Is there a way to display house numbers when using the Nokia Map Image API (the one for static maps)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently the display of house numbers in an image is restricted to the Enterprise version of the Map Image API - this will display when the zoom level is 18 or greater.

[image: House Numbers]

On order to obtain enterprise access click on 'contact us' at the bottom of the [plans](http://developer.here.com/plans) page. Adding house numbers to the free public service is currently under consideration, but isn't available just yet.

Meanwhile, the best alternative would be to use the **i** parameter e.g. `http://m.nok.it/?c=52.4998375,13.3924&nord&i&z=18` - this will geocode the address at the centre of the image.

[image: Address]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I intended to use it for a pet project with about 100 pageviews/day, so paying 1500$/month isn't an option. But neverthless I really like the look of the maps!